# How do I kick off a Console App that runs Selenium web driver using a logic app?

Tags: selenium, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have a Console App that takes advantage of Selenium WebDriver. I'm intending to use this to automate the receipt of an email with an attachment and upload that attachment to a website. The Console App works perfectly. But I'm using WinAutomation to start that process from an .exe on the desktop of a VM.

What I'd like to do is, instead of using winautomation, publish that Console App to an App Service in Azure. This I can do easily. However what I'm wondering is, how would I go about kicking off that App Service and providing the email attachment using a Logic App.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. Selenium requires the use of GDI+ which isn't allowable in an [App Service Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#app-service-plans-and-sandbox-limits). The more plausible course of action is what you're already doing, running your Selenium test during your CI/CD flow on a build agent.